# why for each loop return undefined

Tags: javascript

I need to print every item in the array without using `console.log`.

Any solutions?

```js
function wrap(stringBreak) {
  let text = stringBreak.trim().split(' ');
  text.forEach(element => {
    return element;
  });
}
console.log(wrap('this is a test'));
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return any values. And `wrap` has no `return` statement in itself.

Comment: Did you try just returning `text` (or just `return stringBreak.trim.split(' ');`) and logging that?